# Prove that there doesn't exist a ring isomorphism between a connected ring and the product of 2 non-trivial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having a bit of trouble using the product of rings. Suppose we have a non-trivial and commutative ring $R$ that is connected (i.e. $X^2-X$ has 2 zeroes). Next let $A,B$ be rings and suppose that there exists a ring isomorphism $\phi:R\to A\times B$. I'm trying to prove that either $A$ or $B$ has to be the trivial ring $\{0\}$.

I don't really know how to start solving this problem. Mostly because I'm quite unfamiliar with the product of rings. My main idea of how to solve it, is to somehow prove that $\phi(1)=(1,0)$ or $\phi(1)=(0,1)$. Since a ring isomorphism sends the multiplicative identity of $R$ to the multiplicative identity of $A\times B$, this would hopefully mean that $0$ is the multiplicative identity of either $A$ or $B$. Which would mean that that ring is trivial. To get there I tried using the polynomial $X^2-X$ with $\phi(X^2-X)=\phi(X)\phi(X-1)$. But I can't think of anything else that would help. I haven't used the commutativity of $R$ however, so I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a,b)$ be the multiplicative identity of $R=A\times B$. Then $(0,0)$, $(a,0)$, $(0,b)$ and $(a,b)$ all satisfy $X^2-X=0$, and you are only supposed to have two solutions to this. Thus either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit obvious, but why do $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ satisfy $X^2-X=0$? Do we always have $(x_1,y_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2,y_1y_2)$ and $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of the direct product (or often, direct sum). So $(a,0)^2=(a^2,0^2)=(a,0)$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are nonzero their identities are nonzero. But in that case, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are nontrivial idempotents, which you said do not exist. Therefore $R$ isn't connected.

By contraposition, if $R$ is connected one of $A$ or $B$ is zero.